# Output $error = true if string contains value of mysql-database

Tags: php, mysql

I have strings like these in php,

```
"the quick brown fox eats yellow eggs"
"another sentence"
...
```

as output of

```
foreach ($array as &$value) 
{
  //$value = "the quick brown fox eats yellow Eggs" or another one
}
```

then I have a mysql-database with

```
id,wort
1,fox
2,egg
...
```

I've tried

```
SELECT wort FROM table WHERE word LIKE LOWER('%".$value."%')";
```

Goal is to determine with only the amount of load neccessary within the foreach-loop, whether the $value contains a wort of the mysql-database. If yes, $error = true; else $error = false;

Note:

1. in $value there is Eggs, in mysql-db there is egg, which should still return a $error = true;
2. number of words in value should generally be more than number of wort in the database.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy "SELECT wort FROM `table` WHERE `word` LIKE LOWER('%".$value."%')";

Comment: Do you know what the `&$value` does in your code. And what is exactly in your foreach loop? And please add escaping, otherwise you are vulnerable for SQL injection...

Comment: @Sven wovon redest du?

Comment: Stick to english, please - and look at your posting.

Comment: @Sven Ich kann dir nicht folgen.

Comment: `foreach ($array as &$value)`

Comment: @Sven Ja, und was ist das Problem damit?

Comment: Do you know what the `&$value` does in your code?

Comment: I like the fact your like condition looks for an entire string whereas you only have a single word in the column.

Comment: @Twisted1919 Why do you like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
"SELECT word FROM table WHERE LOCATE(word, LOWER('".mysqli_real_escape_string($value)."')) <> 0 OR LOCATE(LOWER('".mysqli_real_escape_string($value)."'), word) <> 0"
```

Comment: This should be faster and more convenient than doing a PHP filtering

Answer (score 1):

Since your needles are in the database and the haystack is in PHP, you will need to loop through the database and compare it with your strings.

Try this:

```
$array=[
    "the quick brown fox eats yellow eggs",
    "another sentence"
];

$mysqli=new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","password","database");
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT `word` FROM `table`");

while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $words[]=$row['word'];
}

foreach ($array as $value) {
    if (strpos($value,$words)!==false) {
        echo $value." contains a word from the database!\n<br>";
        $error=true;
    }
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of strings and you try to find if they contain words from your database.
In this case, you will have to split your string in multiple words:

```
  $error = false;
  foreach($someArray AS $value) {
    $words = explode(' ', $value);
    foreach($words AS $word) {
       $sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE word LIKE "%'. mysqli_real_escape_string($value).'"'; // use the proper escape function here.
       if( $dbObject->query($sql)->num_rows() > 0 ) {
          $error = true;
          break;
       }
    }
    if($error) {
      break;
    }
}
```

You can also try to load your database words into an array then loop through them, smth like:

```
$error = false;
foreach($wordsFromDb AS $word) {
    foreach($stringsArray as $string) {
        if(stripos($string, $word) !== false) {
          $error = true;
          break;
        }
    }
    if($error) {
       break;
    } 
}
```

Instead of `stripos`, you can use `preg_match()` for a more accurate comparison.
Please note, i didn't test this code, but you should get the idea.

Comment: @Sven - You shouldn't have edit my answer. Everything there serves as an example. I don't know what kind of database or database extension he is using, i just shown him the proper pointers, it is his job to use the right functions to clean the data.

Comment: Feel free to revert the edit. It would be great if you could add an escaping function call of some kind instead of only mentioning it in a comment.

Comment: @Sven - I don't know what db engine/extension he is using. Let's leave the answer as it is, i don't mind now.